# How to fix chromedriver error in console tab?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, console, selenium-chromedriver

I have run my test script but I got this error message in the console tab:

> "Starting ChromeDriver 84.0.4147.30 (48b3e868b4cc0aa7e8149519690b6f6949e110a8-refs/branch-heads/4147@{#310}) on port 30846
> Only local connections are allowed.
> Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
> ChromeDriver was started successfully.
> Aug 22, 2020 5:41:42 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
> INFO: Detected dialect: W3C"

Below is my java code:

```
package seleniumProjectTutorial;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class SeleniumWebDriver {
    
    WebDriver driver;   
    
    public void invokeBrowser() {
        
        try {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","D:\\Selenium\\Drivers\\chromedriver.exe");
            
            driver = new ChromeDriver();
            driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
            driver.manage().window().maximize();
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

            driver.get("https://www.google.com");
            
            driver.close();
            driver.quit();
            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        SeleniumWebDriver myobject = new SeleniumWebDriver();
        myobject.invokeBrowser();
        
        
    }

}
```

Is there a need for me to fix it and how? Thank you.

Comment: Hi cracker, it's not an error. Just a log message. Unless it's causing you any problems you don't need to do anything about it :-)

Comment: Hi @RichEdwards, hmmm. It seems that the Terminate button is still in red even after the successful execution of Java code. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to stop this warning message in the console you need to pass --silent argument to chromedriver to stop console message. you can achieve this using 'withSilent(true)' method

Launch chromedriver using chromedriverservice as shown in below sample code

```
 ChromeDriverService cdservice=new ChromeDriverService.Builder().usingDriverExecutable(new File("/path/to/chromedriver.exe"))
                    .withLogFile(new File("/path/to/chromedriver.log"))
                    .withSilent(true)
                    .usingAnyFreePort()
                    .build();

            WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(cdservice);
            driver.get("http://www.google.com");
```

Comment: Thank you so much guys for your help. :)

Comment: One problem though - 

Now ?

The constructor ChromeDriver(ChromeDriverService) is deprecated